# MS SQL SELECT WITH NO LOCK

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it safe to use SELECT with (NOLOCK) on a table that is never updated?

Comment: Does *never update* include inserts or deletes?

Comment: Yes. No inserts and deletes are being done in that table.

Comment: In this case there's no risk...

Comment: Why do you think you need the NOLOCK? Seems rather useless if no concurrent DML is happening anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it provides IAM scans which can help significantly in the presence of fragmentation. Helps between nothing at all and 10x depending on physical layout.

Comment: @usr: what is an "IAM scan"? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Lot's of stuff about that on the web, including official blogs. An alternative is TABLOCK, or using heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nolock is safe under a very specific set of circumstances. Also, safety is not all or nothing. You might not care about some safety properties.

Nolock scans will sometimes fail if data in the tables moves around physically. Scans also can see rows twice or not at all. If your DML does not cause row movement this shouldn't happen. I'm saying "shouldn't" because this is not formally guaranteed by the product. For example, shrinking a file or migrating it empty should also cause row movement.

Updates can cause insert/delete pairs. Inserts and deletes can cause row movement.

Some specific forms of DML cannot cause row movement in the current implementation of the product although I doubt this is formally guaranteed either. For example, inserts that append to the b-tree being scanned don't cause row movement although the newly inserted row might be missed (I think).

Most of the time, when you use NOLOCK you should expect to very rarely see slightly broken data and very rarely see scans of b-trees fail. If that's alright with you then go ahead.